# why does my script sed command fails though it works fine in command line

Tags: bash, sed

i have written a sed command

```
sed -i '1 a sometext' filename
```

his is working in commandline

but in script the changes are not seen when ran from my script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sudo -i
sed -i "1 a sometext" filename
```

Comment: Remove newline after `sudo` command, don't switch from `'` to `"` and use `filename` with full path or relative to root's home directory.

Comment: tried using single quotes also it doesnt work, and why should i remove new line after sudo command

Comment: It should be `sudo sed -i "1 a sometext" filename` (and this is arguably what you should use interactively as well). The duplicate explains why it doesn't and can't work the way you tried it

Comment: i used double wuoets also my commands after sudois not working not sure why

Comment: Try `sudo -e file.txt`  I'm not sudoer so that's all I can help.