# why does switiching to super user not working from bash

Tags: bash

simple code i tried from my bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
whoami
sudo -i
whoami # this is not working, but my prompt changes to root
```

any help, starting with bash just now, actually i am trying to execute some sed commands through bash, but commands were not executing. If this is solved hope i could work on the remaining

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
sudo -i
sed -i '1 a some text' filename
```

same sed command works fine with command prompt
but none is working, i amnot sure where i am making mistakes

Comment: Close this question and reopen [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60388078/3776858).

Comment: the question is wrong that is why i changed it bro. found that i am not able to execute any command after sudo -i

Comment: anyway i reopened it

Comment: Try `sudo -e file.txt` I'm not `sudoer ` so that's all I can help.

Comment: When you run `sudo -i` (whether it's interactive or in a script), it starts a *new shell*. In a script, that means the new shell isn't reading commands from the script, it's reading them from standard input. By default, standard input is your terminal. To have the script to send commands to that shell, see: [Pass commands as input to another command (su, ssh, sh, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37586811/pass-commands-as-input-to-another-command-su-ssh-sh-etc).